# perform new activity based on QRScan result in Android

Tags: android

I'm relatively new to Android Studio. I'm working on a QR code scanner. I want to do this:

- if `QRscan`'s result is A, then perform new activity
- if the result is B, then perform another activity

Comment: Post your code , what you have done

Comment: use if/else based what response you get.

Comment: user3571701 check my answer below :)

Answer (score 1):

Use Intent

```
   Intent intent;
    if (result is A) {
        intent = new Intent(this, Activity1.class);
    }
    else {
        intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
    }
    startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
@Override
    public void handleResult(Result result) {
        yourResult = result.getText();
        String a = "123";
        String b = "456";

        if (yourResult.toString().equals(a)){
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            //throw result
            i.putExtra("a", a);
            startActivity(i);
        }else if(yourResult.toString().equals(b)){
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ThirdActivity.class);
            //throw result
            i.putExtra("b", b);
            startActivity(i);
        }else{
            //yourcode
        }

    }
```